How do I print out the bubble sort as it goes? (Python)
lst = [6, 3, 0]

keepGoing = True

while keepGoing == True:
    for element in lst:
        thiselem = element
        if lst[lst.index(thiselem)] != lst[-1]:
            nextelem = lst[lst.index(thiselem) + 1]
            if int(thiselem) > int(nextelem):
                lst[lst.index(thiselem) + 1] = thiselem
                lst[lst.index(thiselem)] = nextelem
            print(lst)

and the output is
[0,6,3] 

over and over.
I wanted it to print the sort as it goes like...
[3,6,0]
[3,0,6]
[0,3,6]

AND THEN repeat [0,6,3] over and over. Why doesn't it do that?

When I run your code without any modifications, I do get the behaviour you seem to be after - i.e. it prints  [3, 6, 0], [3, 0, 6], [0, 3, 6], and then repeats [0, 3, 6] endlessly until you "keyboard interrupt" execution.  Is this not the behaviour you want?

Python is just printing too fast and deleting first prints as it prints more, so you miss the first three prints. Try changing "while" to "for":
lst = [6, 3, 0]

keepGoing = True

for i in range(10):
    for element in lst:
        thiselem = element
        if lst[lst.index(thiselem)] != lst[-1]:
            nextelem = lst[lst.index(thiselem) + 1]
            if int(thiselem) > int(nextelem):
                lst[lst.index(thiselem) + 1] = thiselem
                lst[lst.index(thiselem)] = nextelem
            print(lst)


I had no idea that Python or any language did that! Thanks by the way, it works great. That makes sense, but is it all languages that do that or just Python? I know Python can be hard on CPUs so is it just an optimization thing built into Python or VSCode?

Un-terminated while loops run until something breaks for most languages I've encountered... That isn't a python thing per se - it's just your computer obeying the logic you've asked it to execute.

i use pycharm and it did the same thing for me too so it is probably built into python. When it comes to printing stuff, like numbers till 1 billion etc. python is stupidly fast, i assume it deletes stuff for memory because print command is never used to print that many stuff back to back and save... well it looks like it cant anyway. If you want to save stuff you can do it by saving it to a .txt by using open() command

huh, it looks like somebody edited my post. Now i understand why most answers here is seems emotionless. I am rewriting what is deleted that is important: I am a newbie so my information is not that trustable

Executing your code as-written produces the behaviour you seem to be seeking:
[3, 6, 0]
[3, 0, 6]
[0, 3, 6]
[0, 3, 6]
[0, 3, 6]
[0, 3, 6]
...

If you wanted to stop execution after sorting was completed, you'd have to add an else after your if, like this:
lst = [6, 3, 0]

keepGoing = True

while keepGoing == True:
    for element in lst:
        thiselem = element
        if lst[lst.index(thiselem)] != lst[-1]:
            nextelem = lst[lst.index(thiselem) + 1]
            if int(thiselem) > int(nextelem):
                lst[lst.index(thiselem) + 1] = thiselem
                lst[lst.index(thiselem)] = nextelem
            else:
                keepGoing = False
            print(lst)

Running this modified code produces:
[3, 6, 0]
[3, 0, 6]
[0, 3, 6]
[0, 3, 6]

